# Resolve, Solve, Refine, etc., do not work, but Wolfram|Alpha does

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities, wolfram-alpha-queries, resolve

As a teacher, I am trying to show some step-by-step execution. (Any help with tools would be most appreciated.)

Related, I cannot get the following to work:

```
Reduce[{Abs[1 + (1 - 2^x)/(1 + 2^x)] < ε, 0 < ε < 2}, {x}]
```

nor with `Solve[]`, `Resolve[]`, `Refine[]`, etc.

Any ideas?

Interestingly, if I enter:

```
=solve |(1 - 2^x)/(1 + 2^x)+1|< ε, 0<ε<2 for x
```

Wolfram|Alpha solves this -- and *also* reports that `Reduce[]` cannot solve this with the methods available to it.

Comment: You need to add the `Reals` domain, since *Mathematica* assumes everything is complex unless told otherwise: `Reduce[{Abs[1 + (1 - 2^x)/(1 + 2^x)] < ε, 0 < ε < 2}, x, Reals]`

Comment: Thank you very much!  I had seen on the help page: "Reduce[expr,vars] assumes by default that quantities appearing algebraically in inequalities 
are real, while all other quantities are complex." so it did not occur to me that that was necessary.  Did I misunderstand the help page?

Comment: I guess that that description was a bit imprecise, since e.g. `Reduce[{Re[x + I y] < 1}, {x, y}]` will show that the variables are still considered complex, and thus one has to do `Reduce[Re[x + I y] < 1, {x, y}, Reals]`.

Comment: I do not understand, what do you mean by " step-by-step execution"? In your further discussion there is no step-by-step approach, but rather just a trial to solve it by the application of an appropriate function.

Comment: @J.M., thank you for this example. Perhaps I should let the WR folk know.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch, my question came about while building a step-by-step execution, so I thought to ask along the way. Sorry if it was off-topic vis-a-vis my question.

Comment: No, I do not find it off-topic. I was just confused by the term. I understand "step-by-step" as a process in which each small step is done on the blackboard or on the screen: "... now we move this term to the right-hand side of the equation, and then we divide both parts  by two..." Something like this. You probably have something else in mind.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch, yes, that is exactly what I meant. Subsequently, I saw some ideas here on StackExchange from J. M. and m_goldberg, and I am making my own stab at it. The application is for first-year calculus courses, including "epsilon-delta" proofs. Thanx for your interest, and let me know if you'd like to join the effort!  :-)

Comment: *`Reduce[expr,vars]` assumes by default that quantities appearing algebraically in inequalities are real, while all other quantities are complex.* I'm guessing that this refers to statements like `x > 0`. Such a statement make no sense if `x` would be complex, so Mathematica assumes `x` to be real. In your example, the `x` is inside of `Abs`, so the assumption that `x` is complex does not need to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

According to your explanation, I developed a version of step-by-step solving of the inequality in question. I will write `e` instead of `\[CurlyEpsilon]` in order to better visualize it here, on the StackExchange.
Here is the inequality and the domain for `e`:

```
ineq1 = Abs[1 + (1 - 2^x)/(1 + 2^x)] < e
dom=0 < e < 2
```

Let us check, if we need the absolute value function:

```
cond1 = 1 + (1 - 2^x)/(1 + 2^x) > 0;
Reduce[cond1 && x \[Element] Reals]

True
```

That is, the function `Abs[]` is unnecessary if `x` is `Real`. We, thus, form a new inequality:

```
ineq2 = 1 + (1 - 2^x)/(1 + 2^x) < e;
```

Let us now replace `2^x` by `y`:

```
 ineq3 = ineq2 /. x -> Log[2, y]

(* 1 + (1 - y)/(1 + y) < e  *)
```

Let us take the unity into the RHS:

```
ineq4 = Map[Subtract[#, 1] &, ineq3]

(*  (1 - y)/(1 + y) < -1 + e  *)
```

Now we multiply the both parts by `1+y`, expand the RHP and collect the terms with `y` in the RHP:

```
ineq5 = Map[Times[#, 1 + y] &, ineq4] // Expand // Collect[#, y] &

(*  1 - y < -1 + e + (-1 + e) y  *)
```

Now let us bring unity in the RHP, while the term containing `y` to the LHP and cancel there:

```
ineq6 = Map[Subtract[#, 1 + y (-1 + e)] &, ineq5] // Collect[#, y] &

(*   -e y < -2 + e   *)
```

and finally divide by `e`:

```
ineq7 = Map[Divide[#, -e] &, ineq6]

(*  y < -((-2 + e)/e)  *)
```

Now let us check, if the RHP of the obtained inequality is positive:

```
Reduce[-((-2 + e)/e) > 0 && dom]

(*  0 < e < 2  *)
```

The answer is yes. Then recalling the definition of `y`one can simply find the logarithm of both parts:

```
x < Log[2, -((-2 + e)/e)]

(*   x < Log[-((-2 + e)/e)]/Log[2] *)
```

Done.

Have fun!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91320/discussion-on-answer-by-alexei-boulbitch-resolve-solve-refine-etc-do-not-wo).